# Add (click) method to link in text block in Angular component

Tags: html, angular, overriding

I have a small problem. I'm getting a text from the server with innerHtml which is inserted in Angular component. Inside of this text, there are possibly some links. Example text block looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<a href="some.link.com">Link<a/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Is there a way to insert a bind there a click action like this?

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<a href="some.link.com" (click)="methodName('http://domain.tld/page.html')">Link<a/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, have you even tried it?

Comment: Yes I did and I did not find a way to add such binding in my case where I got this text from server with innerHtml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, you render html loaded from server with innerHtml, in this case you can't use Angular directives inside of this template. But you can add listeners with common JS (document.addEventListener) after content rendering.

```
@Component({
  template: `<div #wrapper [innerHTML]="sanitizedHtml"></div>`
}) class MyComp {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     const links = this.wrapper.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a[href]');
     links.forEach(link => 
       link.addEventListener('click', this.linkClickHandler.bind(this));
     );
  }

  linkClickHandler(event: MouseEvent) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does and that what I was doing, but I was hoping that there Is a way of maybe a place something like a dynamic component or some other way to bind a click.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest way you'll get, you could try to use `@ViewChildren` instead of `querySelectorAll()` but apart from that this is a good answer.

Comment: you can take a look at Angular Elements, but this is to much for this case... I think. If you need handle clicks in multiple components, you can create directive for wrapper and use it like that `<div linksWrapper (linkClick)='handle($event)' [innerHTML]="html"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic links you can bind your desired `url` link in you `a` tag like the following

```
<a [href]="some.url">Link</a>
```

If `some` is an object.

For click event you can have something like

```
method(url: string) {
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

then you'll pass your `url` string like `(click)="method('http://domain.tld/page.html')"`